# Resolve Cycles and Multiple Cascade Paths

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a set of tables and am currently trying to set up the correct relationships for the tables. The condensed version is below.

```
Users
    ID INT NOT NULL

Activities
    ID INT NOT NULL
    UserID INT NULL

Logs
    ID INT NOT NULL
    UserID INT NULL
    ActivityID INT NULL
```

I have relationships relating `UserID` from both `Activities` and `Logs` back to `Users.ID` and `ActivityID` relating back to `Activities.ID`.

I have set `Activities.UserID` and `Logs.UserID` to set null on delete, and cascade on update. My problem comes when i attempt to set the same update and delete functions to `Logs.ActivityID` but i get an error about "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths". My problem is, `Logs` Require a User, and do not require an `Activity`, but, `Logs` that do have an `Activity` need to be updated if and when an `Activity` changes.

What way do i have around this that does not involve having two separate `Logs` tables, and does not involve manually updating the `Logs` table. Is this even possible in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with cascade? I suspect that deleting a user is a pretty uncommon incident, and you can write your own delete logic around that that deletes (or sets NULL) the values manually, before deleting the user.

Comment: What is the point of cascade and set null if i cant actually use them? the point is, they are there to be used and i would like to be able to get around the ridiculousness of sql-servers shortcomings over practically EVERY other sql engine without having to write the delete and null logic myself

Comment: A lot of things exist in SQL Server that were written with the simplest implementations in mind, and weren't tested for (and therefore aren't supported in) more complex implementations. FWIW, I have never used CASCADE in production, for this and other reasons. If it is that important to you to have CASCADE work automatically when there are multiple paths, then by all means, use another database platform. Of course you'll spend more time converting your schema and code than you would writing a procedure that does this for you...

Comment: Are IDs really supposed to change? Why would you change an ID (assuming that's a PK)?

Comment: I also don't know why you'd ever delete a user. In all the industries I've been involved in, you always "soft" delete any end user data.

Comment: And there's another train of thought where having nullable columns is considered ridiculous. And having 4 instead of 3 tables when needed is considered good practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server does not support multiple cascade paths. Your options to work around this limitation are:

1. write your own logic for dealing with multiple cascade paths (recommended).
2. change your schema such that multiple cascade paths are not required.
3. wait for SQL Server to fix this. Don't hold your breath - this has been a limitation for years. See these Connect items:

   a. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/126159/cascade-updates

   b. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/307723/allow-multiple-cascade-paths-for-foreign-key-and-on-dalete-update-cascade

   Notice how they keep saying "we don't have time for this now; we'll consider it for the next release"? This isn't the kind of thing that sells software, because people are satisfied - generally - with coding the logic themselves.
4. migrate to a database platform that supports multiple cascade paths (sounds like you think you have many options for this, but I don't think you do, and I don't know what you sacrifice by switching, not even counting porting your schema and code).

Comment: This is a new project, it would be entirely possible for me to switch to mysql, or pgsql, especially with sql-server's limited grasp on SQL, i could more or less script the tables and data i have now and run them on a new engine. this may be the option i end up going for.

Comment: @bizzehdee Great, have fun! Most people don't have that kind of flexibility. Hopefully later on in this project you don't come across a limitation of mysql or pgsql that makes you want to switch back.

Comment: @bizzehdee it's not a limited grasp of "sql." in fact there are many logical reasons to NOT support multiple cascade paths which is why most rdbms' will force any developer who thinks that this is a good idea to do it on their own. of course, mysql and it's standards-breaking ways may be a good choice for you now that you'll regret later. this brings up a good point - think of your future self and how much they will hate your present self for such a "unique" design.