# Simple example - Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table aaaIsChildOf' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I tried to implement a simple **A depends on B** relationship  in sql:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.AdependsonB', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.AdependsonB;
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.aaaPerson', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.aaaPerson;

CREATE TABLE aaaPerson
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] VARCHAR(40) 
)

CREATE TABLE AdependsonB
(
    [IsChildOf] INT NOT NULL,
    [Parent] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_AdependsonB] PRIMARY KEY ([IsChildOf],[Parent]),
    CONSTRAINT [CHK_identity] CHECK ([IsChildOf] <> [Parent]),  
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AdependsonB_IsChildOf-aaaPerson_id] FOREIGN KEY ([IsChildOf]) REFERENCES aaaPerson(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AdependsonB_Parent-aaaPerson_id] FOREIGN KEY ([Parent]) REFERENCES aaaPerson(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
```

When running these lines of code, I got following error:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint'FK_AdependsonB_Parent-aaaPerson_id' on table aaaAdependsonB' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths**

When omitting "**ON DELETE CASCADE**" at either foreign key constraint the code runs perfectly but it would not be correct semantically.

Can anyone give advice why and what to do in such case?
I already read a lot regarding this problem, but I do not get it why a such simple relation can't be implemented without any workaround.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243365/resolve-cycles-and-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: Why does the child table need both IsChildOf and Parent? Can you explain how these two are different? Is parent really "top parent"?  And can't this relationship be expressed more simply - you should always be able to get to the top parent by following the hierachical path. You can probably have all of this information in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to take caution on entering some kind of scenario where a father can get a lot of sons and deleting a son causes the deletion of the father and that make all sons to be deleted (can you see the loop here?).

Those kind of logic can lie on business layer and is better handled (delete all brothers and so on delete father).

And the parser is right that is not feasible nor reasonable, you are (possibly) creating a cycle of multiple cascade paths with that redundant [IsChildOf] and [Parent] columns.

Cannot you use just a self reference FK? What do you want to achieve?